# How can I get around a UniqueConstraint error when inserting data into postgresql with flask?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a model that I use to insert data into a postgresql database using flask:

```
class UserSchema(Schema):
    class Meta:
        ordered = True

    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    username = fields.String(required=True)
    affiliation = fields.String(required=True)
    email = fields.Email(required=True)
    password = fields.Method(required=True, deserialize='load_password')

    created_at = fields.DateTime(dump_only=True)
    updated_at = fields.DateTime(dump_only=True)
```

The problem is, when I add a user to the db that has the same affiliation as another user in the db, I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates 
unique constraint "user_affiliation_key"
DETAIL:  Key (affiliation)=(dev) already exists.
```

Surely there's a way to insert duplicate values into postgresql. I tried using unique=false for that field, but it didn't work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the sqlalchemy model code, and the output of `\d <table-name>` in psql.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had Unique = True set in the model. @snqkecharmerb thanks for pointing that out.